# How can I do number is bigger or smaller than a percentage of a veritable?

Tags: python-3.x

Lets say x = 10
y is an input number a user can input which could be any number.

I want to say if y is larger than two percents of x or less than two percents of x than its pass. anything else is print fail.

Comment: `y > 1.02 * x or y < 0.98 * x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want?

```
if y > 0.02 * x or y < 0.02 * x:

    // pass

else:

    //fail
```

This will achieve the same goal :

```
if y != 0.02 * x:

    // pass

else:

    //fail
```

Comment: This is what he asked for, further, this will execute falsely when y == 0.02*x

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it can be depicted that you want the if statement to be executed only if `y` is `less than` or `greater than`  `2% of x`, in that case you do the following:

`if y  != 0.02 * x: //statement`

Comment: It should be `if y  != 0.02 * x`  you forgot a 0. It says 2 percent (0.02) not twenty percent (0.2)

Comment: Pardon me for the omission of a '0' there, which could hell lot of a difference, thanks for correcting me!